# Traing a Spacy NER model I get an exception: "[E022] Could not find a transition with the name 'B-COMPANY' in the NER model."

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

For a reproducible example, I will provide toy data and the code:

The training data are the following (19 records):

```
to_train_ents  = [('  δηµοσίευσης  στο  διαδικτυακό  τόπο του Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. στοιχείων της ανώνυµης εταιρείας µε την επωνυµία «ΑΛΟΥΜΥΛ, ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΑ ΑΛΟΥΜΙΝΙΟΥ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΙΑ».    Την 25/07/2019 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εµπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) µε Κωδικό Αριθµό Καταχώρισης',
  {'entities': [(100, 146, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('ΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ   Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «ΑΝΕΚ ΤΟΥΡΙΣΤΙΚΗ - ΞΕΝΟΔΟΧΕΙΑΚΗ - ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΩΝ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ».  Την 18/12/2017 καταχωρίσθηκαν στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.), τα κατωτέρω στοιχεία της Ανώ',
  {'entities': [(100, 160, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('ς στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) στοιχείων της ανώνυμης τραπεζικής εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «ATTICA BANK ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΤΡΑΠΕΖΙΚΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ»     Ανακοινώνεται ότι την 91-2020 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) με Κωδικό Αρι',
  {'entities': [(100, 138, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυμης τραπεζικής εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «ATTICA BANK ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΤΡΑΠΕΖΙΚΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ». Ανακοινώνεται ότι την 18112019 καταχωρίστηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.)  με Κωδικό Αριθ',
  {'entities': [(100, 138, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('ΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ  Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «ΔΕΗ SOLAR SOLUTIONS ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ», το διακριτικό τίτλο «ΔΕΗ SOLAR SOLUTIONS AE» και Αριθμό Γ.Ε.ΜΗ  129809601000.   Ο ΠΡΟΕΔΡΟΣ  ΤΟΥ Ε',
  {'entities': [(100, 136, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 (' και δημοσίευσης στο διαδικτυακό τόπο του Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «Ελληνικά Πετρέλαια Ανώνυμη Εταιρεία».  Την 111-2019 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) με Κωδικό Αριθμό Καταχώρησης 162',
  {'entities': [(100, 135, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('6806                                                     ΚΑΤΑΣΤΑΤΙΚΟ ΤΗΣ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑΣ ΜΕ ΤΗΝ ΕΠΩΝΥΜΙΑ «ΕΛΛΗΝΙΚΑ ΠΕΤΡΕΛΑΙΑ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ»                                                   ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ Α΄ Επωνυμία – Έδρα – Διάρκεια – Σκοπός ',
  {'entities': [(100, 135, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('ΑΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ  Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία FORTHNET ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ΣΥΝΔΡΟΜΗΤΙΚΗΣ ΤΗΛΕΟΡΑΣΗΣ, ΠΑΡΟΧΗΣ ΤΗΛΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑΚΩΝ ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΩΝ και το διακριτικό τίτλο FORTHNET MEDIA Α.Ε.  Την 13/11/2018 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώ',
  {'entities': [(99, 201, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('ΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ  Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο, στοιχείων της Ανώνυμης Εταιρείας με την επωνυμία FORTHNET ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ΣΥΝΔΡΟΜΗΤΙΚΗΣ ΤΗΛΕΟΡΑΣΗΣ, ΠΑΡΟΧΗΣ ΤΗΛΕΠΙΚΟΙΝΩΝΙΑΚΩΝ ΥΠΗΡΕΣΙΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΣΥΜΜΕΤΟΧΩΝ, το διακριτικό τίτλο FORTHNET MEDIA Α.Ε και αριθμό ΓΕΜΗ 124012301000.  Ο ΠΡΟΕΔΡΟΣ  ΤΟΥ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΟΥ & ',
  {'entities': [(99, 201, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('και δημοσίευσης στο διαδικτυακό τόπο του Γ.Ε.ΜΗ., στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «JUMBO ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ».  Ανακοινώνεται ότι την 11.12.2019 καταχωρίσθηκαν στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.), τα κατωτέρ',
  {'entities': [(100, 131, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('ΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ  Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της Ανώνυμης Εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «JUMBO ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ».      Ανακοινώνεται ότι την 11.12.2019 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) με Κωδικ',
  {'entities': [(100, 131, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('και δημοσίευσης στον διαδικτυακό τόπο του Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. στοιχείων της Ανώνυμης Εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «ΣΥΣΤΗΜΑΤΑ ΜΙΚΡΟΫΠΟΛΟΓΙΣΤΩΝ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ». Την 16.02.2016 καταχωρίστηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) με Κωδικό Αριθμό Καταχώρησης 56',
  {'entities': [(100, 143, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('αι δημοσίευσης στον διαδικτυακό τόπο του Γ.Ε.ΜΗ., στοιχείων της Ανώνυμης Εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «ΠΛΑΙΣΙΟ COMPUTERS ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΗ ΚΑΙ ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΝΙΚΩΝ ΥΠΟΛΟΓΙΣΤΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΕΙΔΩΝ ΒΙΒΛΙΟΧΑΡΤΟΠΩΛΕΙΟΥ».      Ανακοινώνεται ότι την 07.08.2019 καταχωρίσθηκε, εκ νέου, στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ)',
  {'entities': [(100, 213, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('  δημοσίευσης  στο  διαδικτυακό  τόπο του Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «ΠΛΑΙΣΙΟ COMPUTERS ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΗ ΚΑΙ ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ΗΛΕΚΤΡΟΝΙΚΩΝ ΥΠΟΛΟΓΙΣΤΩΝ ΚΑΙ ΕΙΔΩΝ ΒΙΒΛΙΟΧΑΡΤΟΠΩΛΕΙΟΥ». Την 18/06/2018 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.) µε Κωδικό Αριθµό Καταχώρισης 14',
  {'entities': [(100, 213, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('µ. Πρωτ. :    1826463                           ΚΩΔΙΚΟΠΟΙΗΜΕΝΟ ΚΑΤΑΣΤΑΤΙΚΟ  ΤΗΣ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗΣ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑΣ «Quest Συμμετοχών Ανώνυμη Εταιρεία» Αρ. Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. 121763701000  ΚΕΦΑΛΑΙΟ  Α Σύσταση – Επωνυμία – ΄Εδρα – Διάρκεια Σκοπός  ΄Αρθρο 1 Η επω',
  {'entities': [(100, 133, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('ΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ  Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «TITAN ΔΙΕΘΝΗΣ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΗ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ΤΣΙΜΕΝΤΩΝ».  Ο ΠΡΟΕΔΡΟΣ ΤΟΥ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΟΥ & ΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΟΥ ΕΠΙΜΕΛΗΤΗΡΙΟΥ ΑΘΗΝΩΝ Ανακοινώνει ότι:  Την 10/06/2019 κα',
  {'entities': [(100, 149, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 ('Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.), στοιχείων της Ανώνυμης Εταιρείας με την επωνυμία «TITAN ΔΙΕΘΝΗΣ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΗ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΗ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ ΤΣΙΜΕΝΤΩΝ» και αριθμό Γ.Ε.ΜΗ. 1604901000, (που είχε Αρ.ΜΑΕ. 29226/001/Β/93/0346).  Ο ΠΡΟΕΔΡΟΣ  ΤΟΥ ΕΜΠΟΡΙΚΟΥ ',
  {'entities': [(100, 149, 'B-COMPANY')]}),
 (' ΑΝΑΚΟΙΝΩΣΗ Καταχώρισης στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο στοιχείων της ανώνυμης εταιρείας με την επωνυμία ΒΙΑΝΕΞ Α.Ε. ΑΝΩΝΥΜΟΣ ΕΜΠΟΡΟΒΙΟΜΗΧΑΝΙΚΗ ΤΟΥΡΙΣΤΙΚΗ ΞΕΝΟΔΟΧΕΙΑΚΗ ΚΑΙ ΝΑΥΤΙΛΙΑΚΗ ΑΝΩΝΥΜΟΣ ΕΤΑΙΡΕΙΑ και το διακριτικό τίτλο ΒΙΑΝΕΞ ΑΕ. Την 03/04/2019 καταχωρίσθηκε στο Γενικό Εμπορικό Μητρώο (Γ.Ε.ΜΗ.',
  {'entities': [(99, 194, 'B-COMPANY')]})]
```

The code is the following:

```
def train_model(to_train_ents, nlp):

    optimizer = nlp.begin_training()

    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != 'ner']

    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):

        for itn in range(20):

            losses = {}

            random.shuffle(to_train_ents)

            for item in to_train_ents:

                nlp.update([item[0]], 

                          [item[1]],

                          sgd = optimizer,

                        drop = 0.35,

                          losses = losses)


    return(nlp, losses)
```

I use the Greek Spacy model (md) which is installed and loaded with the following code:

```
!python -m spacy download el_core_news_md
nlp_el = spacy.load('el_core_news_md')
```

Then I call the function train_model() previously defined and I get the following error:

```
nlp_el , losses = train_model(to_train_ents, nlp_el)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-484-a059cf596651> in <module>
----> 1 nlp_el , losses = train_model(to_train_ents, nlp_el)

<ipython-input-471-56fdae8ff98f> in train_model(to_train_ents, nlp)
     23                         drop = 0.35,
     24 
---> 25                           losses = losses)
     26 
     27 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\spacy\language.py in update(self, docs, golds, drop, sgd, losses, component_cfg)
    450             kwargs = component_cfg.get(name, {})
    451             kwargs.setdefault("drop", drop)
--> 452             proc.update(docs, golds, sgd=get_grads, losses=losses, **kwargs)
    453             for key, (W, dW) in grads.items():
    454                 sgd(W, dW, key=key)

nn_parser.pyx in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser.update()

nn_parser.pyx in spacy.syntax.nn_parser.Parser._init_gold_batch()

ner.pyx in spacy.syntax.ner.BiluoPushDown.preprocess_gold()

ner.pyx in spacy.syntax.ner.BiluoPushDown.lookup_transition()

KeyError: "[E022] Could not find a transition with the name 'B-COMPANY' in the NER model."
```

How you explain the error and how can I remedy it?

Comment: Did you add `COMPANY` as a label to the NER model with `ner.add_label("COMPANY")` ? I don't think it's in the generic label scheme of the pretrained Greek models.

Comment: Thank you Sofie.  Could you provide the few lines of code that would be needed to complement my code in your view?  As my code has, there is no 'ner' object defined.

Comment: Right! You can do `ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")` and then the `add_label` function for every new label you want the NER to train on.

Comment: Thank you Sofie.  That worked.  But I am getting a single value in `losses`. I.e.: `{'ner': 487.23682813020423}`.  Should n't I get 20 values since I had 20 iterations?

Comment: I've added my comments as a proper answer, as this would help others reading this question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`COMPANY` needs to be added to the NER model:

```
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
ner.add_label("COMPANY")
```

You need to do this for each entity type in your data that is not yet in the labelset of the [pretrained Greek model](https://spacy.io/models/el) (For 2.2.5, this is: EVENT, GPE, LOC, ORG, PERSON, PRODUCT)

Also, you redefine `losses` every iteration. Instead, you probably want to print it / store it each loop so you can check the loss curve.